# Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove some characters at the end of a certain list of item. These characters are always the same (C, CD, PDF, CPDF, M) and with this regular expression I'm able to get rid of them :

```
str.replaceAll("(C|CD|PDF|CPDF|M)$", "");
```

However, I'm not able to inverse this expression : I'd like to be able to isolate (by removing the rest of the string, for exemple) any of these code, if they're at the end of the string. I tried this :

`str.replaceAll("!(C|CD|PDF|CPDF|M)$", "");`

I probably get by using some string functions, but I'm sure it's possible using only regular expression.

Comment: What do you mean by 'invert this expression'? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It sounds like he wants to remove all suffixes that aren't in that set.  However, that doesn't make sense, so I'm not sure.

Comment: a wild guess, I would say he wants to find out what he actually removed.

Comment: I edited the description to answer your questions. Basically, if I get this string : "165N1JCD", I want to obtain the  "CD" part. Since I can get the "165N1J" part, I figured it's not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I never expected to have so much feedback in such a short time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're already using parenthesis to capture the matching group, now simply reference that group.

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(C|CD|PDF|CPDF|M)$").matcher("165N1JCD");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); // prints out "CD"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as Josh Hight, except for the regexp that allow to get both parts

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*)(C|CD|PDF|CPDF|M)$").matcher("165N1JCD");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); // prints out "165N1J"
        System.out.println(m.group(2)); // prints out "CD"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Matcher class to grab a specific group (the suffix you remove) and perform the replaceAll operation. Another option would be to make your expression have two groups, the one you have and one before it for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Matcher class, you can stick with replaceAll:

```
str.replaceAll(".*(C|CD|PDF|CPDF|M)$", "$1");
```